# Regex for dutch phone numbers that works inside a sentence or if concatenated

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regex that will find a dutch phone number inside a piece of text. For example:

- Mijn telefoonnnummer is 0612131415
- Mijn telefoonnnummer is 06-12345678
- Mijn telefoonnummer0612131415email

Is shouldn't detect

- 000006121314150000
- -0612131415-
- 00-0612131415-00

This regex (https://regexr.com/3aevr) seems fine for detecting seperate values:

```
^((\+|00(\s|\s?\-\s?)?)31(\s|\s?\-\s?)?(\(0\)[\-\s]?)?|0)[1-9]((\s|\s?\-\s?)?[0-9])((\s|\s?-\s?)?[0-9])((\s|\s?-\s?)?[0-9])\s?[0-9]\s?[0-9]\s?[0-9]\s?[0-9]\s?[0-9]$
```

Unfortunately it does not work for my purposes. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
(?<![^a-zA-Z\s])((\+|00(\s|\s?-\s?)?)31(\s|\s?-\s?)?(\(0\)[-\s]?)?|0)[1-9]((\s|\s?-\s?)?[0-9])((\s|\s?-\s?)?[0-9])((\s|\s?-\s?)?[0-9])\s?[0-9]\s?[0-9]\s?[0-9]\s?[0-9]\s?[0-9](?![^a-zA-Z\s])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/06qhjR/1).

The `(?<![^a-zA-Z\s])` negative lookbehind makes sure there is an ASCII letter or a whitespace char, or start of string immediately to the left of the current location.

The `(?![^a-zA-Z\s])` negative lookahead makes sure there is an ASCII letter or a whitespace char, or end of string immediately to the right of the current location.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this regex:

```
(?<![\d\-])\d{2}-?\d{8}(?!\d)
```

Explanation:

- `(?<![\d\-])`: Negative lookbehind that doesn't matches ...

  - `[\d\-]`: a digit or a dash (at the beginning of your number)
- `\d{2}`: two digits
- `-?`: optional dash
- `\d{8}`: eight digits
- `(?!\d)`: Negative lookahead that doesn't matches ...

  - `\d`: a digit (at the end of your number)

Try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/HAeCke/1).

**Note**: Lookbehind and lookahead in this regex ensure there are no more than 10 digits in your string (the ones inside the matching pattern).

Comment: It works for the example data ++ (but note that the regex link in the question has more examples, which is not clear from the question though)

Comment: Yes @Thefourthbird, here the attempt it to generalize at best given the provided samples, yet trying to keeping it simple. If the combinations go a lot out of the scope of the provided samples, this regex may not be sufficient and Wiktor's great solution will help him definitely.